# Find the last one to change a file?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

Working several people on a local line, each logged with its users/pwd, is it possible to know who made the last modify on a file?

Is it possible to know the original author, but I do not find the possibility to view the last saver user

I use Office 2007

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Word and Excel 2010, I can go to File/Info and I see

[image: Word File/Info]

This should work as long as nobody uses the Document Inspector to remove personal data from the file.

Comment: I edited the question because I use MS-Office 2007 (anyway thanks for this info about new release)

Comment: This tool / behavior  is  same  back to  XP and  office/excel from 97